# How to Inpect Content of a Function?

Tags: javascript

There is a function called **ytPlayerSIZE_CLICKED2** on Youtube.com. I want to inspect the code of that function. Using the below code does not give me enough information via Firebug console:

```
alert(ytPlayerSIZE_CLICKED2.toString())
```

How can I find the contents of that function via Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Take out the the invoking parentheses.

```
alert(ytPlayerSIZE_CLICKED2.toString)
```

Comment: It does not help. It creates this:                                             function toString() {
    [native code]
}

Comment: toString is a core JS method hence why you see native code instead of the actual code. Try to use console.log instead, perhaps it will give you more.